# ckeditor error textarea not editable on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog

i am using ckeditor in  jquery dialog. it works fine with mozilla and IE but not editable on chrome.

i removed the instances but still gives type error on chrome

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please paste some code so we can see what you are doing? Also, please paste the error you are getting.

Comment: Perhaps that will help you http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087 and http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10081

Comment: I often experience this issue - restarting Chrome usually fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I've had with ckeditor not displaying in Chrome is when the language setting of ckeditor doesn't match the language setting in Chrome. So as I'm in the UK, in the 'lang' folder of ckeditor I have the file 'en-gb.js', and the language setting in Chrome as English (United Kingdom).